# Accessing an enum in a namespace

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

In a header I have a setup like this

```
namespace NS {
    typedef enum { GOOD, BAD, UGLY }enum_thing;
    class Thing {
        void thing(enum_thing elem);
    }
}
```

and of course another cpp file that goes along with that header. Then I have a thread cpp file that contains main(). In this cpp file I use that enum to pass to the method thing().

```
using namespace NS;
int main() {
    Thing t();
    t.thing(BAD);
}
```

and of course I get other errors from G++ saying BAD was not declared. Any help on how I could overcome this error?

Comment: it should be `Thing t;` not `Thing t()`

Comment: a `public:` is missing before the method and a `;` is missing at the end of the class declaration, after the closing `}`.

Comment: What if you fully qualify the enum: `NS::BAD`. Older compiler dislike this. typedefing in C++ is not needed in such cases. Here an anonymous enum is getting typedef'ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you avoid using a typedef?  Just do:

```
enum Foobar {good, bad, hello};
```

Answer (score 5):

After correcting numerous little syntax errors in the sample code, it compiles just fine for me.  Check that you've spelled the names correctly.  Can you access the enum as NS::BAD?  Perhaps you haven't included the correct header?  Make sure you have 
`#include "FileWithEnum.h"` at the top.

```
namespace NS {
    typedef enum { GOOD, BAD, UGLY }enum_thing;
    class Thing {
        public:
            void thing(enum_thing elem){}
    };
}


using namespace NS;
int main() {
    Thing t;
    t.thing(BAD);
    return 0;
}
```

Test it yourself:
http://codepad.org/Uw0XjOlF

Answer (score 0):

It should work. It does for me (the variant by Mystagogue should also work). I understand you had some other error messages ?

You probably just have to fix the header to be syntaxically correct, like putting a semi-colon at the end of class Thing, etc. When the header will be OK, the message about BAD not in namespace should also disappear.